# Does SQL Developer have enough features to support daily DBA jobs?

Tags: oracle

Does SQL Developer have enough features to support the daily jobs for an Oracle DBA? 
Compared to TOAD, what is missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL developer can do the job for a developer but still has it's share of quirks.

- I found that the connection screen would not display if the file path it is installed in contains a space.  (Windows XP, SQL Developer Version 3.1.07).
- I had it installed for someone to do data updates and they got the "Data committed in another session".  This bug has been around since version 1 and is easily resolved by fiddling with the settings but it's unfortunate to see in what should be a mature product.

It also lacks some of the tools DBA's use to maintain the health such as:

- tablespace visualizer
- extent management
- pinning code (if you still need to do that)

I like the Toad option to compare database schemas or find an object that is named or contains a text string.

You can't beat a free tool, and one that is constantly being added to. Toad benefits from many more years of development.

Edit: it can analyze indexes and copy a table. thanks @Phil!

Comment: > copy a table to another schema with or without data

You can do that. Right-click on the table in the tree and click copy. It gives you a dropdown for the schema.

> analyze indexes

Right-click, compute statistics

Comment: a professional DBA administers his Oracle with sqlplus. The sqlplus-way is part of the OracleCertification.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer and Toad play in 2 different domains.

SQL Developer is a development tool and Toad is a more of a DBA's tool (at least it started as so). SQL Navigator is the equivalent to SQL Developer from Quest. Still both the tools have cross-functional features.

Yes, SQL Developer is still young it'll add more features with the time.

But right at the moment, Toad is better in functionality/ performance/ feature set/ usability etc...